# How to print the values of the List<List<String[]>> in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, csv

I want to get the values of the individual arrays from the list and utilize them

```
 import java.io.FileReader;   
 import java.util.ArrayList; 
 import java.util.List;
 import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;


public class ReadCSV {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String startFile = "/Users/ray/Downloads/hello.csv";
    //String outFile = "./outData.xml";

    try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(startFile));
        String[] line = null;

        String[] header = reader.readNext();

        List<List<String[]>> out = new ArrayList<List<String[]>>();

        while((line = reader.readNext())!=null){
            List<String[]> item = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                String[] keyVal = new String[2];
                String string = header[i];
                System.out.println("the value of the header : "+string);
                String val = line[i];
                System.out.println("the value of the field : "+val);
                keyVal[0] = string;
                keyVal[1] = val;
                item.add(keyVal);
            }
            out.add(item);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
  }
```

I have a csv file of the following format:-

```
Keyword,AlternateKeywords---> these are the header fields
apple,banana
orange,ego kit
ego ce4,venus
demo,cat
```

I want the Arrays in form of:

```
array[] keyword={apple,orange,ego ce4,demo}
array[] banana={banana,ego kit,venus,cat}
```

I do not know how to get the data from the List 'out' and get the values and print the elements as above. It can be any number of headers and any number of elements for that particular column, the above csv is just an example.

Please help me if possible.

Comment: ego ce4,venus - should "ego" be there in this line?? .. I mean the i/p which you have shown, is it correct?

Comment: sorry I do not understand@Rohit, please specify in details what is your question? I have specified my requrements in details.thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over your list ?

Comment: yes here "Keywords" and "AlternateKeywords" are the headers for the respective columns. Please help,any idea?

Comment: How to iterate? that is what I am not getting....I have to basically iterate out to get the arrays from the list, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on your structure:

```
array[] keyword={apple,orange,ego ce4,demo}
array[] banana={banana,ego kit,venus,cat}
```

You dont need 3D like `List<List<String[]>>` but only 2D `List<List<String>>`

Here is working code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String startFile = "C:\\workspacePrototype\\some.csv";

    try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(startFile));
        String[] line = null;

        String[] headers = reader.readNext();


        List<List<String>> build = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        List<String> tempArr;

        // generate headers
        for(String header : headers){
            tempArr = new ArrayList<String>();
            tempArr.add(header);
            build.add(tempArr);
        }


        // generate content
        while((line = reader.readNext())!=null){

            for (int i = 0; i < build.size(); i++) {
                tempArr = build.get(i);
                String val = line[i];
                tempArr.add(val);
                build.set(i, tempArr);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(build));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 [[[Keyword, apple, orange, ego ce4, demo], [AlternateKeywords, banana, ego kit, venus, cat]]]
```

**[EDIT]**

BTW, you can create some class like:

```
 public class Column{
  private String mName;
  private List<String> mData;

  // get/set
 }
```

and instead

```
 List<List<String>> build = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

use like:

```
 List<Column> build = new ArrayList<Column>();
```

by this way `Column` class should store column name to `mName` and data to `mData`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion and but I do not want the Headers in the arrays just the elements after the header. any further help will be appreciated, without the "Keyword" and "AlternateKeyword".

Comment: just comment `tempArr.add(header);`

Comment: Your Program works and then how to get individual arrays that was my actual Question from the arraylist as above@Maxim